# ApplicationMailer convention - passing data vs. lookup in the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've noticed that the accepted convention with ApplicationMailers is to keep the logic inside to a bare minimum and pass needed data into the mailer method itself, rather than looking up data (ActiveRecord records) inside the mailer method. I haven't really found an explanation *why* this is preferred though - can anyone explain why this is the trend?

For example:

```
class FooMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # OK
  def foo_email(recipient, widget)
    @widget = widget
    mail(to: recipient, from: 'foo@bar.com', subject: 'Your widget')
  end

######
# VS #
######

  # Not OK
  def foo_email(recipient)
    @widget = Widget.first
    mail(to: recipient, from: 'foo@bar.com', subject: 'Your widget')
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word (okay, three): [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In the former example, the `ApplicationMailer` doesn't need to know anything about your models. And, it doesn't contain any business logic related to selecting a `widget`.

In the latter example, `ActionMailer` both (1) needs to know something about your models (there's a thing called `Widget`) and (2) contains business logic (`Widget.first`).

Comment: I had a feeling that was the reason. Thanks for confirming!